# magento 2.2.0 Error:: "you did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled"

Tags: magento2.2.0

I Installed Magento version 2.2.0. But I am getting error "you did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled"

Comment: Please make sure you are using correct username and password of admin. Also please try on another browser OR clear browser cookies and try.

Comment: Go to this file path and \vendor\zendframework\zend-crypt\src\Utils.php and echo $expected and $actual variable and check both are same or not if both variable are not match then change line no 35

if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return hash_equals($expected, $actual); }

To

if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return true; }

Comment: Above solution is working for me, Is this a right way.

Comment: You should not change any core file of Magento. Did you try in another browser?

Comment: Also please try after deleting pub/static folder and clear caches of Magento

Comment: Created new admin account through CLI. That's working for me. Above given solution by me is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command and check, it might be help to you

> php bin/magento admin:user:unlock yourAdminUserName